# Preserve raw JSON string of a property

Tags: java, json, gson

I am using the Gson parser in Java 7. I would like to preserve one of my properties as a raw JSON string so I can deserialize it into the desired class later.

Example input JSON:

```
{
    "foo":"bar",
    "body":["blah"]
}
```

or

```
{
    "foo":"bar",
    "body":{"a":"b"}
}
```

Deserializes to a class like this:

```
public class Message {
    public String foo;
    public String bar; //I want this to be a raw JSON string, not parsed
}
```

Code:

```
String input = "{\"foo\":\"bar\", \"body\":[\"blah\"]}";

Message message = gson.fromJson(input, Message.class);

message.foo; //"bar"
message.body; //"[\"blah\"]"
```

Is this possible?

UPDATE:

I'm currently doing this, but it would be nice if it could be "cleaner" and use the native `String` type somehow...

```
public class Message {
    public String foo;
    public JsonString body;
}

public static class JsonString {
    public String body;
}

public static class JsonStringDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<JsonString> {
    @Override
    public JsonString deserialize(JsonElement json, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext context) {
        JsonString a = new JsonString();
        a.body = json.toString();
        return a;
    }
}
```

The thing I don't like about this is that I have to use the deserialized object like so:

```
Message message = gson.fromJson(input, Message.class);

//notice how i have to use the inner string
SomeClass cls = gson.fromJson(message.body.body, SomeClass.class);
```

Comment: I'd create a custom annotation and my own class that implements `JsonDeserializer<T>`; and write the `deserialize` implementation in such a way to perserve the `JsonElement` as a `String`. You can then use `registerTypeAdapter` apart of `GsonBuilder` to construct a `Gson` which is aware of this annotation.

Comment: please see my updated question! i think i did something similar, but its a bit undesirable (may be unavoidable though).

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind declaring your `body` property as an `Object` instead of a `String` to get around JSON decoding problems; you can do the following.

Annotation definition for `JSONRawString`:

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface JSONRawString {
}
```

The `Message` class:

```
public class Message {
    public String foo;

    @JSONRawString
    public Object body;
}
```

The deserializer:

```
public class JSONRawStringDeserializer<T> implements JsonDeserializer<T> {
    @Override
    public T deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext) throws JsonParseException {
        //We decode using the normal deserializer; but will run over all the fields and check if our annotation exists. This is a bit hacky; but should work if you don't mind declaring your objects which you'd like to maintain as deserialized as Object.
        T serializedObject = new Gson().fromJson(jsonElement, type);
        Field[] fields = serializedObject.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            if (field.getAnnotation(JSONRawString.class) != null) {
                try {
                    String fieldName = field.getName();
                    if(field.getAnnotation(SerializedName.class) != null) {
                        fieldName = field.getAnnotation(SerializedName.class).value();
                    }

                    String element = new Gson().toJson(jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get(fieldName).toString());
                    field.set(serializedObject, element);
                } catch(IllegalAccessException e) {
                    throw new JsonParseException(e);
                }
            }
        }

        return serializedObject;
    }
}
```

Finally in `Main`:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(Message.class, new JSONRawStringDeserializer<Message>())
                .create();

        String input = "{\"foo\":\"bar\", \"body\":[\"blah\"]}";

        Message message = gson.fromJson(input, Message.class);
        System.out.printf("message.foo: %s, message.body: %s", message.foo, message.body);
    }
}
```

Resulting in `message.foo: bar, message.body: "[\"blah\"]"`

This is sort of hacky; because we override what Gson would have spit out with our own method; and I don't think this works recursively. Hopefully it will lead you to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `JsonDeserializer`, it's better to use the newer `JsonReader`/`JsonWriter` interface provided by gson's TypeAdapter.

See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50537019/332798